# Suddenly unable to export to war file from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I been working on this Servlet project all morning and now suddenly I cannot get eclipse to export the project to a war file. I tried restarting eclipse and cleaning the project but I just get the same result. Any ideas?

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Extended Operation failure: 
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.archive.operations.WebComponentExportOperation
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard.performFinish(DataModelWizard.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ExportResourcesAction.run(ExportResourcesAction.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$4.run(Workbench.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1173)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException[0]: org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingWar File
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactExportOperation.execute(J2EEArtifactExportOperation.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1$CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:113)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: IWAE0017E Unable to replace original archive: C:\Users\mark\uploads\myfirstjsp.war
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.cleanupAfterTempSave(ArchiveImpl.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.saveAsNoReopen(ArchiveImpl.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.archive.operations.WebComponentExportOperation.export(WebComponentExportOperation.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactExportOperation.execute(J2EEArtifactExportOperation.java:95)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: In fact, the last one is very informative: "Unable to replace original archive". Post your solution as answer so you can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess I should have read the whole error as it does say that the problem is it can't write to the file. The interesting part was what was causing the file to be locked. Firefox had the file open so eclipse couldn't write to the file. I have no idea why firefox had the file open though I was using it to upload the war file to the server.