# Different behaviours for two identical JAXWS deployed in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jax-ws

I have implemented two JAXWS which are exactly the same.

Concat-WS takes a string a concatenates a word.
Upshift-WS takes a string and upshifts it.

I deployed them in Tomcat and created two JAXWS clients with the wsimport tool.

When I run the Concat client it works, but with the Upshift client it throws:

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: No Content-type in the header!

I've read a few posts about this. All of them seem to be related to [JBOSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193580/jax-ws-exception-javax-xml-ws-webserviceexception-no-content-type-in-the-hea) which is not my case, besides, how can two exact JAXWS have different behaviours?

**EDIT**

Here is the Upshift webservice

```
package upshift;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "upshift.Upshift")
public class UpshiftImpl implements Upshift {

    @Override
    public String upshift(String x) {

        return x.toUpperCase();

    }
}
```

Here is the Concat webservice

```
package concat;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "concat.Concat")
public class ConcatImpl implements Concat {

    @Override
    public String concat(String x) {

        return x.concat("+concat");

    }
}
```

**EDIT II:**

I have found that the second JAXWS had issues when it was exported as a WAR. 
Everytime I try to export it as a WAR I get the following:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingC:/Users/rmescalera/Desktop/WS-upshift.war
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getModuleParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.createFlatComponentArchiver(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.export(ComponentExportOperation.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:136)
    ... 10 more
```

Still it generates the WAR, but I guess it has errors and that's why I get the `No-Content type in header` when consumed. So now, the question is, why does it throw this error when exporting? Again, being the exact same as the other web service.

**EDIT III:**

I've opened a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687740/error-when-exporting-from-jaxws-to-war-in-eclipse#comment18806901_13687740) that follows my progress. Still don't know what the problem was but as I explain in my comments I suspect it has something to do with the endorsed standards mechanism

Comment: Could you post the classes that implement @WebService? Your problem is hard to tell without actual code.

Comment: the code looks fine, so I guess the problem lies in deployment. Tomcat does not come with a default JAX-WS implementation. So where did you put the libs? In Tomcat's lib directory or in each of the webapps? (Did you maybe forget it for the upshift service?)

Comment: @joergl, they're both in the WEB-INF/lib directory. They both have the exact same 18 jars. Any other ideas?

Comment: unfortunately not really. It most certainly is not an issue in the services code (they run with `Endpoint.publish(...)` for me). So it must be a configuration / deployment problem. I would recommend checking all your environment settings and / or maybe reinstalling eclipse. If you are exporting the war via a wizard, rather do it with a small ant script where you are in control of everything.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725249/suddenly-unable-to-export-to-war-file-from-eclipse This is not your exception, but your problem could be similar. Is some process locking the file you are trying to export to? Alas, the `NullPointerException` doesn't tell.

Comment: thx @joergl, that doesn't seem to be my case. I have added a new EDIT that might give some hints.