# Error when exporting from JAXWS to WAR in Eclipse

Tags: export, jax-ws, war

I am getting the following error when trying to export a JAXWS as a WAR in Eclipse:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingC:/Users/rmescalera/Desktop/WS-upshift.war
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getModuleParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.createFlatComponentArchiver(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.export(ComponentExportOperation.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:136)
    ... 10 more
```

The thing is I have created another JAXWS exactly the same way with the exact same jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory with no issues.

Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: All of a sudden I could finally export the WAR, but when testing both WS the other one doesn't work now. I suspect the jars in their libs directories can't coexist. It must have something to do with the endorsed standards mechanism which I am reading about right now.

Comment: Or eclipse was just messing with you. Go netbeans :)

Comment: @kolossus, I'm afraid of having to start all over again with a new IDE. Anyhow, I fix it by deploying the JAXWS in Tomcat instead of Jetty.